# Foreground service that does nothing. Is it a good candidate to be killed by the OS?

Tags: android

Maybe the question is obvious, but I would like to be sure based on what my app does.

I am writing a GPS tracker. I use the location services inside a static class to get my positions. Everything works fine. However I have noticed that from time to time my app gets killed when it has been running for a couple of hours. In order to resolve that I thought in converting it to a foreground service.

Instead of rewriting my code and put all my logic inside the service, I thought in just creating a foreground service that does nothing. I will start this service when the user decides to start tracking. Remember that I use the location services inside a static class.

Will this be safe or the OS will find out that this service is not doing anything at all and it will have more chances to be killed?

Here is my service:

```
public class SimpleService extends Service 
{
    private static final int ONGOING_NOTIFICATION = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() 
    {
        super.onCreate();

        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "Tracking started", System.currentTimeMillis());
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "notification title", "notification message", pendingIntent);     
        startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION, notification);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() 
    {
          super.onDestroy();          
          stopForeground(true);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a similar thing for a service I created that ran periodically to download a file if it changed but found it was being killed by the OS after several hours.  Since using `startForeground`, the problem has gone away.

I don't think there'd be a difference between my service that does minimal work and your empty one.